# Hyper-V host Ubuntu shared folder E514 write error on second write

Tags: hyper-v

Host: Windows 10
Guest: Hyper-V virtual machine: Ubuntu 18.0.4
Problem with shared folder: Can edit and write a new file only once.
On second write:

Virtual-Machine-Ubuntu-18-04-3-LTS:~$ vi    shared-drives/D:/HYPERV_SHARED_FOLDER/test
Virtual-Machine-Ubuntu-18-04-3-LTS:~$ cat     shared-drives/D:/HYPERV_SHARED_FOLDER/test
First write of shared folder file: ok
Virtual-Machine-Ubuntu-18-04-3-LTS:~$ vi    shared-drives/D:/HYPERV_SHARED_FOLDER/test
Error on write:
"shared-drives/D:/HYPERV_SHARED_FOLDER/test"
"shared-drives/D:/HYPERV_SHARED_FOLDER/test" E514: write error (file system full?)
WARNING: Original file may be lost or damaged
don't quit the editor until the file is successfully written!
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue.  I wasn't able to resolve it on the VM side, instead I created network shares for the folders I needed access to and mounted those from the VM.

So far this has been pretty painless, a guide is available for the windows side here:

https://linuxhint.com/shared_folders_hypver-v_ubuntu_guest/

And for the Ubuntu side to enable permanent share mounting here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.